# How to remove extraneous horizontal line ParametricPlot of Mod function in evaluation

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make plot of the mod function in the parametric plot.
But it gives extraneous horizontal line.

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -0.05y[t]-Sin[x[t]]+0.8Cos[0.7 t], x[0] ==0, y[0] ==0}, {x, y}, {t, 1000}];
Show[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Mod[x[t]+Pi,2Pi]-Pi, y[t]} /. sp18],{t, 1000-6Pi, 1000},PlotRange->{{-Pi,Pi},All}]]
```

I checked that there is no horizontal line when I made plot without Mod in following, there is no horizontal line.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sp18],{t, 1000-6Pi, 1000},PlotRange->All]]
```

How can I get the correct Plot?

Comment: The horizontal line is created by the Mod function. It creates jumps in the x coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I understand more on the problem...Can I ask how can I eliminate that jump?

Comment: You could e.g. plot up to the jump. And in a second plot from the other side of the jump further on. Using "Show" you can plot all plots in one picture.

Comment: Thank you again. But then I think I need to know which parameter the jump occurs.
But, I don't know x[t] jumps at which parameter 't'. ( Mod[x[t],2Pi]==0 ).
Is there smart method that I can find it?

Comment: I wrote an answer to show where the jumps occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mod function jumps when its argument is a multiple of 2Pi.To get an idea where Mod[x[t]+Pi,2Pi] jumps, you can first draw the argument of Mod:

```
fx[t_] = 
  x[t] /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], 
      y'[t] == -0.05 y[t] - Sin[x[t]] + 0.8 Cos[0.7  t], x[0] == 0, 
      y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 1000}][[1]];
Plot[{fx[t] + Pi, -109  2  Pi, -110  2  Pi}, {t, 1000 - 6 Pi, 1000}]
```

[image]

Therefore the jumps happen at approx.: t= 984 and t= 994. To get an accurate value we may use FindRoot:

```
FindRoot[fx[t] + Pi + 109  2 Pi , {t, 984}]

{t -> 984.936}

FindRoot[fx[t] + Pi + 110  2 Pi , {t, 994}]

{t -> 993.912}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sp18=NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -0.05y[t]-Sin[x[t]]+0.8Cos[0.7 t], x[0] ==0, y[0] ==0}, {x, y}, {t, 1000}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sp18],{t, 1000-6Pi, 1000},PlotRange->All]
```

and we solve the `k` which satisfies the range belong to `{-Pi,Pi}`

```
Solve[-Pi < 1000 - k*2*Pi < Pi, k, Integers][[1]]
```

> `{k -> 159}`.

and we plot  `{t, 1000 - 159*2 Pi, 1000 - 151*2 Pi}` and found that it is not a periodic function, so use `Mod` is not so right.

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sp18], {t, 1000 - 159*2 Pi, 
  1000 - 151*2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for careful check for the function. Yes, it is not periodic. But the value 't' stands for angle and I want a parametric plot with parameter 't'. I think even if it is not periodic, I can get a some more complicated plot without horizontal line.